# Live Linux CD for burn-in with Bonnie++?

Tags: linux, livecd, burn-in

Is there a live linux distro that I can use for burn-in? I'd like something that has Bonnie++ on it. I've found other live CDs that have utilities, but nothing with bonnie++ on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[StressLinux](http://www.stresslinux.org/sl/)

> StressLinux is a minimal linux
>   distribution running from a bootable
>   cdrom (LiveCD) or via PXE. Stresslinux
>   is dedicated to users who want to test
>   their system(s) entirely on high load
>   and monitoring the health.
>
> Features:
>
> - stress 0.18.1 (A tool to impose certain types of stress on a POSIX
>     system.)
> - CPUBurn 1.4 (CPU maximum load (heat) stability test)
> - CPU Burn-In 1.00 (CPU burn-in test)
> - nbench 2.2.1 (CPU test suite)
> - iometer 2003.12.16 (I/O performance meter)
> - hddtemp 0.3beta11 (A program to display the temperature of your hard
>     drive.)
> - lm_sensors 2.8.7 (LM78 and other hardware monitor drivers.)
> - busybox 1.0.0rc3 (Single small executable which contains common UNIX
>     utilities)
> - lshw A.01.07 (Hardware lister)
> - **bonnie++ 1.03a (Hard drive benchmark)**
> - netio 1.23 (Network benchmark)
> - smartmontools 5.32 (S.M.A.R.T. drivetests)
> - x86info 1.12b (CPU information)
> - memtest86 3.1a (A stand-alone memory diagnostic)
> - memtest86+ 1.15 (An other stand-alone memory diagnostic)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at another distro named [Parted Magic](https://partedmagic.com/).  It specializes in everything that has to do with hard disks and includes bonnie++ among other things.

Comment: Parted Magic is included with the [http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/](Ultimate Boot CD), which is a bootable CD which contains many diagnostic utilities. Many of these utilities are otherwise only available via a floppy disk image.